Unable to find io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2 in Android Studio for Flutter project
I'm trying to install the io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2 plugin in my Flutter Android project. My project is using Android Studio, and my ext.kotlin_version is set to 1.6.10. The plugin is supposed to be available on JCenter, but my project is giving the following error:
Could not find io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2.
I've tried adding JCenter to my repositories, but it's still not working. How can I resolve this issue and successfully include the plugin in my project? Is there an alternative source or workaround?
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
        classpath 'io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2'
        classpath "com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

If i try to use 0.33 version, can successfully download. but getting runtime error.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithParanoidForDevDebug'.
> kotlin.jvm.internal.MutablePropertyReference1Impl.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V


Couldn't find 0.22 version jre file

I need to install 0.22 version
I need jre file of 0.22 version
I need to fix issue of 0.33 version


Problem seems to be related to Kotlin compatibility and the availability of the plugin on repository like JCenter.

Switch to an Alternative Repository as JCenter has been deprecated. For more check this: https://developer.android.com/build/jcenter-migration

Many libraries are moving to other repositories like Maven Central.
Find the repo url you need and add here in repositories:
maven { url "[repo_url_here]" }


The error is showing that there is compatibility issue between Kotlin 1.6.10 and the paranoid-gradle-plugin 0.3.3.

There are 2 ways to fix this error:

Downgrade Kotlin to a version that is compatible with paranoid-gradle-plugin 0.3.3

Alternatively, if you need to stick with Kotlin 1.6.10, consider checking if there's a newer version of the plugin that supports Kotlin 1.6.10 


Find the JAR File for 0.22 Version:


If you need version 0.22 specifically and can't find it via repositories, you may need to manually download the JAR file and include it in your project. Place the JAR in your project libs folder and include it in your build.gradle
This must resolve your issues :)
